# How can you change the text in a resource in an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, resources

I want to change the text in the resource to the text changed in the activity.

What I'm trying to access in the activity.
university_name_campus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="abc"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/total_univer_name"
    >
</TextView>
```

Some of the activities that modify text

```
if(intent.hasExtra("name")){
            university_name_campus.text=intent.getStringExtra("name")
            
        }
```

Ultimately, I want to change the "abc" of the university_name_campus from activity.

Comment: use textview.setText(stringfromIntent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's easy.

```
//use this after View has been created, such as in onViewCreated

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if(intent.hasExtra("name")){
            //you need to use the id of the element you want to change.
            // use findViewById

            val universityName:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.total_univer_name)
            universityName.text=intent.getStringExtra("name")
           
        }
}
```

Hope This helps you out.